# Partial autocomplete of the suggestions given by vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible for the autocomplete feature of vscode to accept only part of the suggestions on <kbd>Tab</kbd>?

Basically, we can specify the word separators characters in settings but the autocomplete feature seems to ignore these and replace the complete full word either way.

What I want, for example, is that by specifying the word separator `"_"` the autocomplete won't replace the full suggestion but only until this character which should effectively be considered the end of the word.

For example, having `semi_completions_foo()` declared and having written only the initial `"se"`.

`"se"` + <kbd>Tab</kbd> -> `"semi_"`

`"semi_"` + <kbd>Tab</kbd> -> `"semi_completions_"`

On the other hand by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> the full suggestion would be accepted.

`"se"` + <kbd>Enter</kbd> -> `"semi_completions_foo"`

Is this already implemented?

Comment: AFAIK there is no such function available by default, you might want to check for a plugin in order to do this.

Comment: Thank you. Thought so, just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not supported by default as of VS Code 1.35 but is tracked by [this feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/61426).

However VS Code does support tabbing through suggestion alternatives after you accept a completion with `tab`. Just press `tab` again to switch to the next suggestion from the list.